# My raspberry is stuck on this screen upon power up, please help!

Tags: pi-3

[image: ANYONE CARE TO HELP]

Could anyone help me? My Pi is stuck on this screen when it powers up.

Comment: You may need to install a desktop environment like lxde, if this is your first boot-up based on the distro you chose, it could be completely normal. Try running `startx`

Comment: that is not `stuck` ... it is at a command prompt ... it will do whatever you tell it to do

Comment: What distribution did you download or install on your machine?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. I see a more or less standard Linux login, why did you expect something else?

Answer (score 3):

Please, before working with any computer, or any device at all, **read the documentation**!

Official documentation for Raspberry Pi is here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/

What you might like, is here: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/raspberry-pi-intro/latest/raspberry-pi-intro.pdf. Read the part 2.3, "Start up", and you will find:

> After the computer is finished loading the operating system you land
>   in the shell.

After this, you will find, how to configure everything and start a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

first, try running `startx`. if that doesn't work, it means you probably don't have the desktop installed(maybe you have raspbian lite). To install the default raspbian pixel desktop make sure your connected to the internet then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xserver-xorg
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xinit
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-ui-mods
```

then type 'startx'

[click here for more info and a full tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=133691)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the screenshot you have provided, you are logged in as user "pi" on Raspbian. I assume your RPi is not frozen, it accepts your typed input, you have installed the operating system "Raspbian Stretch with desktop" and you are stuck in how to get to this desktop. (If this is not the case, please provide more details.) Based on this I recommend:

1. Boot your RPi (it should be like shown in your screenshot), run from the command line `sudo raspi-config`, press Enter and now you should see a main menu with several options (like this [screenshot](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/images/raspi-config.png)).
2. Navigate with the arrow keys (down/up) to **3 Boot Options         Configure options for start-up** and press Enter.
3. Navigate to **B1 Desktop / CLI** and press Enter.
4. Navigate to the desired setting (might be **B4 Desktop Autologin**) and press Enter. It will beam you back to the main menu.
5. Navigate with the arrow keys (right/left) to the option **Finish** and press Enter.
6. The answer to "Would you like to reboot now?" should be **Yes**.

In case you wanted your RPi to boot a desktop environment, you should be happy now.

To change the boot option later from the desktop: open **Menu > Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration** and change the option in the tab **System**.

Answer (score 0):

Check the free space left in your sd card! I got the same exact issue and the only thing that actually worked for me was cleaning up some space through the command prompt bacause the sd was full!!